# Вывод массива новостей от JSON

Tags: javascript

Мне надо вывести все новости, взятые от JSON в блок с id='content'. Как это сделать? JSON забираю так:

```js
function GET(mode, id) {
  if (mode == 'news') {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://w-0rld.ru/mode?type=news',
      success: function(data, textStatus) {
        console.log('Полчили новости:\n' + data);
        if (textStatus == 'success') {
          var json4ik = JSON.parse(data);
          $("#container").html('<div id="title"><div id="title_text">' + json4ik[0].news.title + '</div></div><div id="content"><div id="content_text">' + json4ik[0].news.content + '</div></div>');
        }
        if (textStatus == 'error') {
          alert('Ошибка при загрузке новостей.');
        }
        if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
          alert('Потеряно соединение с сервером.');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
<a href='#' onclick="GET('news')">ПОЛУЧИТЬ НОВОСТИ</a>
```

Покажите пример что-бы он показывал не одну, а все новости.

Comment: А в чем у вас затруднение-то?

Comment: В том что я не знаю как это сделать и за что хвататься.

Comment: Схватитесь за debugger: посмотрите, что вам возвращает сервер, и что оказывается в переменной `data` – есть подозрение, что `JSON.parse()` не нужен. Далее действуйте по обстоятельствам. Если там массив, пройдитесь циклом `for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) { news = data[i]; // дальше делайте html из очередной новости }`

Comment: Как это парсинг не нужен? Повторюсь мне нужно из json-списка сделать список новостей.

Comment: @W_0rld, вам просто нужен цикл. А это одна из базовых конструкций любого языка. Советую начать разбираться с циклами и задавать уже более конкретные вопроосы.

Comment: Я знаю. Но не одного дельного примера или урока не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Так как никто не ответил, решил сделать такой костыль. Так как я не знаю как получить количество всех новостей, я решил принудительно показывать 10 новостей.

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
$("#container").append('<div id="title"><div id="title_text">'+json4ik[i].news.title+'</div></div><div id="content"><div id="content_text">'+json4ik[i].news.content+'</div></div>');
}
```